# How to create image slider with webgl textures in react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, glsl, shader, webgl, react-three-fiber

I am currently trying to transition through an array of images using webgl shaders and react three fiber and I am stuck. Trying to use buttons to navigate through rather than just clicking on the canvas. Unsure how to pass / change imageOne and imageTwo with left and right arrow. Is this possible?

I'm aware how to do an image slider in react alone but confused with the two image properties for the glsl mix property. All help is appreciated.

Inspiration: https://yuta-takahashi.dev/

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-cdn-os34di?file=/pages/index.js